# Magento Product Forms Dropdown Labels & Values

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute, labels

I have a dropdown attribute, TruckID.

I have 2 values Val1,Val2.(Visible) however, when they save I need these to be .08 & .10.

We actually have dozens of values, but the workflow I have to have. I see there on many other 'admin' forms for contact, etc, but for Magento Product Attributes, I'm not sure how to assign something different that what the admins see in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you can change in the labels tab of your attribute.

In this tab you have at least (depending if you're running multi stores or not) two columns: **admin** and **frontend**.

You can set .08 for admin and val1 for frontend and so on that would do the trick.

Comment: I'm not too worried about what would show up on the front. What I'll need is what would show up over our API. I need it easier for our admins to choose a correct value, but it has to be by these truckIDs.

Comment: We mapped a 'Calculated' store for what we needed to do over the API. Thanks for the heads on the direction as it seemed to work the best.